# Why does google chrome's console have different representations of the document object between page refreshes?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, document, global

In a attempt to determine for myself the reliability of the "document" variable in the Chrome Browser I built a simple HTML file like such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       console.log( document )
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I assumed that this would cause the value of the "document" variable to be echoed to the console on every page load and would be the exact same every time.

Yet this is not what happens. On the first refresh the console outputs a "Document" object and  on the next refresh it outputs a "HTMLDocument" object and so on, toggling back and forth between the two.

Can anybody explain what is going on here?

Screencast:  http://youtu.be/q0r_Q0wW8f8

Comment: This is still true though the output is slightly different that in my original question. Load that file in Chrome, open the console and check the console output, then refresh and check it again: It jumps between two different representations of the document object at each page refresh. I'm really curious as to what is going on.

Comment: For me it just says `#document`

Comment: @ExplosionPills Click on that to expand it. Then refresh and click on that to expand it. You will not see the same representation of the object.

Comment: Here's a screencast of the behaviour I'm getting,  http://youtu.be/q0r_Q0wW8f8